# uniquely identify images from json in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

[Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZO1L.png)[Example Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoUki.png) I'm creating an app in ionic/angular and fetching the data from JSON object which is working quite well but it having some repeated images like one company have many deals and for every deal have the same image.
I want to create one unique image by which user click on that and user gets all the deals from that company. I tried using angular filter "unique" but it didn't work. 
Thanks for reading kindly give me some advice to solve this issue.

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


     $http.get("my.json").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;

      $scope.stack=[];
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(item){

        $scope.stack =item.store_image;
        var uni_img=[];
        for(var i=0 ; i< $scope.stack.length ; i++)
        {
            if(uni_img.indexOf($scope.stack[i] == -1))
                uni_img.push($scope.stack[i]);
        }
         console.log("Unique Technologies : " + uni_img);
      // its logging image link in console but how to display on front end 

      })    


  });
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Deals</th>

                </tr>
                <tr class="list card" ng-repeat="da in uni_img  ">
                    <td> <img class="thumbnail center-block img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.uni_img }}" />{{da.category}}</td>

                    <td></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

Json  like

```
{
featured: "0",
exclusive: "0",
promo_id: "P59802",
offer_id: "2239",
offer_name: "Zotezo.com CPS - India",
coupon_title: "Zotezo Crazy4",
category: "Home & Kitchen",
coupon_description: "TnC: [Free Shipping] [COD not available]",
coupon_type: "Promotion",
coupon_code: "",
ref_id: "utm_source=vCommission&utm_medium=CPS&utm_content=Deals-of-the-Day&utm_campaign=vCommission",
link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotezo.com%2Feveryday-wellness%3Futm_source%3DvCommission%26utm_medium%3DCPS%26utm_content%3DDeals-of-the-Day%26utm_campaign%3DvCommission",
coupon_expiry: "2017-01-31",
added: "2017-01-05",
preview_url: "http://www.zotezo.com/everyday-wellness",
store_link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766",
store_image: "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/2239/zottezo-2.jpg"
},
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the json response?

Comment: check the image

Comment: I mean the `my.json`file contents.

Comment: Share your my.json in plunker or jsfiddle so that it will be easy to solve

Comment: actually its url in which my api keys are there i cant share openly

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to do anything in controller. By default angular does not have unique filter. But angular ui does have unique so you can dependency inject that one into your module.Look at the store_image in json. First store_image is different from others and rest are similar hence removed duplicates. Below is the working example

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters']);

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = "hello";
  
  $scope.data = [{
      featured: "0",
      exclusive: "0",
      promo_id: "P59802",
      offer_id: "2239",
      offer_name: "Zotezo.com CPS - India",
      coupon_title: "Zotezo Crazy4",
      category: "Home & Kitchen",
      coupon_description: "TnC: [Free Shipping] [COD not available]",
      coupon_type: "Promotion",
      coupon_code: "",
      ref_id: "utm_source=vCommission&utm_medium=CPS&utm_content=Deals-of-the-Day&utm_campaign=vCommission",
      link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotezo.com%2Feveryday-wellness%3Futm_source%3DvCommission%26utm_medium%3DCPS%26utm_content%3DDeals-of-the-Day%26utm_campaign%3DvCommission",
      coupon_expiry: "2017-01-31",
      added: "2017-01-05",
      preview_url: "http://www.zotezo.com/everyday-wellness",
      store_link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766",
      store_image: "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/2239/zottezo-1.jpg"
      },
      {
        featured: "0",
      exclusive: "0",
      promo_id: "P59802",
      offer_id: "2239",
      offer_name: "Zotezo.com CPS - India",
      coupon_title: "Zotezo Crazy4",
      category: "Home & Kitchen",
      coupon_description: "TnC: [Free Shipping] [COD not available]",
      coupon_type: "Promotion",
      coupon_code: "",
      ref_id: "utm_source=vCommission&utm_medium=CPS&utm_content=Deals-of-the-Day&utm_campaign=vCommission",
      link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotezo.com%2Feveryday-wellness%3Futm_source%3DvCommission%26utm_medium%3DCPS%26utm_content%3DDeals-of-the-Day%26utm_campaign%3DvCommission",
      coupon_expiry: "2017-01-31",
      added: "2017-01-05",
      preview_url: "http://www.zotezo.com/everyday-wellness",
      store_link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766",
      store_image: "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/2239/zottezo-2.jpg"
      },
      {
        featured: "0",
      exclusive: "0",
      promo_id: "P59802",
      offer_id: "2239",
      offer_name: "Zotezo.com CPS - India",
      coupon_title: "Zotezo Crazy4",
      category: "Home & Kitchen",
      coupon_description: "TnC: [Free Shipping] [COD not available]",
      coupon_type: "Promotion",
      coupon_code: "",
      ref_id: "utm_source=vCommission&utm_medium=CPS&utm_content=Deals-of-the-Day&utm_campaign=vCommission",
      link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotezo.com%2Feveryday-wellness%3Futm_source%3DvCommission%26utm_medium%3DCPS%26utm_content%3DDeals-of-the-Day%26utm_campaign%3DvCommission",
      coupon_expiry: "2017-01-31",
      added: "2017-01-05",
      preview_url: "http://www.zotezo.com/everyday-wellness",
      store_link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766",
      store_image: "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/2239/zottezo-2.jpg"
      },
      {
        featured: "0",
      exclusive: "0",
      promo_id: "P59802",
      offer_id: "2239",
      offer_name: "Zotezo.com CPS - India",
      coupon_title: "Zotezo Crazy4",
      category: "Home & Kitchen",
      coupon_description: "TnC: [Free Shipping] [COD not available]",
      coupon_type: "Promotion",
      coupon_code: "",
      ref_id: "utm_source=vCommission&utm_medium=CPS&utm_content=Deals-of-the-Day&utm_campaign=vCommission",
      link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotezo.com%2Feveryday-wellness%3Futm_source%3DvCommission%26utm_medium%3DCPS%26utm_content%3DDeals-of-the-Day%26utm_campaign%3DvCommission",
      coupon_expiry: "2017-01-31",
      added: "2017-01-05",
      preview_url: "http://www.zotezo.com/everyday-wellness",
      store_link: "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2239&aff_id=48766",
      store_image: "http://media.vcommission.com/brand/files/vcm/2239/zottezo-2.jpg"
      }
  
  
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <th>Brand</th>
              <th>Deals</th>

          </tr>
          <tr class="list card" ng-repeat="da in data | unique: 'store_image'">
              <td> <img class="thumbnail center-block img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image }}" />{{da.category}}</td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.filters' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Have you added angular-ui script to your html file?

Comment: angular.module('app', ['ionic','ui.filters','app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives',])

Comment: You have to add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks mate its working now i made a stupid mistake  of typing .. Thanks